# What is "a wait on a notification handle" in the Windows API?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to figure out how to use FindFirstChangeNotification in order to do some file monitoring (in this case, for hot-reloading settings). I'm a bit a confused about what this function returns. From the docs, it creates a "change notification handle". Ok, sure. But then "A wait on a notification handle succeeds when...". In this context, what is a "wait"?

Comment: See WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects. A *wait* is exactly  what it sounds like; waiting for a notification that a change has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the "wait" refers to wait for the "change notification handle", which is a kind of `HANDLE` that you can **wait until it is in signaled** state by using [Wait Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069(v=vs.85).aspx).

A minimal example would be like this:

```
static void MyNotifyDirChange(HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR szPath)
{
    HANDLE hWaitNotify = ::FindFirstChangeNotificationW(
        szPath, TRUE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY);
    if (hWaitNotify == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ::MessageBoxW(hwnd,
            L"FindFirstChangeNotificationW failed.",
            nullptr, MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }
    ::WaitForSingleObject(hWaitNotify, INFINITE);
    ::MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Dir change notify.",
        L"Notify", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

[WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) waits until the specified object is in the signaled state or the time-out interval elapses. Since I've specified `INFINITE`, it will stay at there forever until the handle became signaled. And when the handle became signaled, it means something has happened; the files in the directory have changed or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wait Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN:

> Wait functions allow a thread to block its own execution. The wait functions do not return until the specified criteria have been met.

Most of the wait functions (the notable exception being WaitOnAddress) accept one or more handles that determine the criteria for returning from the wait.  To wait on a handle means to pass the handle to one of these wait functions.  It is also common to refer to waiting on an object, which has the same meaning as waiting on a handle to that object.

[Synchronization Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364(v=vs.85).aspx) lists the various kinds of objects you can wait on: events, mutexes, semaphore and waitable timers; change and memory resource notifications; jobs, processes and threads; and (subject to some caveats) I/O handles.